# Impact of past status violation in US on UK visitors visa

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

I had a US student status (F-1 status) violation due to unauthorized employment in the past as I failed to renew my I20 during my internship unintentionally due to pure lack of knowledge. I was able to get my status reinstated by traveling and reentering the USA on a new I20.

I want to know if I will ever be issued with a visitors visa for UK considering the violation in USA which was worked upon with immediately.

Comment: We cannot tell you what decisions UKVI will reach.
Do you have a question that is answerable by this community. (Eg, would this make you ineligible for a UK visitior visa)

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you meet the criteria (eg stable financials, ties to home country)?  How long ago was the US violation? AFAIK it wouldn’t mean an *automatic* refusal but the only way to know for sure is to apply. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1032802/Non-conducive_grounds_for_refusal_or_cancellation_of_entry_clearance_or_permission.pdf

Comment: The violation was last year and worked upon with reinstatement within 20 days.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question that you seem to be trying to ask:

**It is not impossible that you will get a UK visa, despite your violation of US visa rules.** Having violated US visa rules does not make you ineligible for a UK visa.

However the UK authorities will know about your violation of US rules, and will consider it when deciding whether to give you a visa. Obviously the fact that you violated rules of another country will make them think you are more likely to violate the rules of the UK, and this will make them much less likely to give you a visa.

Whether or not you get a visa is dependent on a lot of things, and nobody can say for certain whether or not you will get one. It will be much more difficult that if you had not broken the US rules.

Comment: you're probably overselling the concern here; if the US considers the problem minor enough to have permitted re-entry, it is certainly reasonable that the UK will not care all that much either. but your conclusion is correct that the only way to know for certain if a visa will be issued is to apply for one.